# How to test that if an API is compatible across multiple library versions in Spring/Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, testing

I want to find a way that I can test an API is compatible with my library versions.

I'm developing an API - keeps changing - but backward compatible all time (maybe). Also developing a library that uses the API which I made.

like this:

my-server-api

- has 1 endpoint returns all of resources that I need.
- but I need to add or modify the response of the endpoint sometime.

my-library (uses my-server-api's response)

- has multiple versions 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, ...
  ...

Both of applications are built in Kotlin, SpringBoot, Gradle.

So I want to test automatically that all of my library versions are compatible with current API. If I can run the tests by Github Actions would be best.

What is the best solution for this? Any keywords would help me so much.

Thank you.

I've done research about it, but I couldn't fine the solution that uses Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought using github webhooks? https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/about-webhooks

You could imagine having your api being deployed in a web server, and then every time you create a release of your library, you can run tests in your pipeline against the web server where your api is deployed.